# Spring JPA Costum Return Type with Join

Tags: java, spring, jpa

```
public class UserTransfer{
    private String u_email;
    private String u_password;

    public UserTransfer(String u_email,String u_password) {
        this.u_email=u_email;
        this.u_password=u_password;
    }

    public String getU_email() {
        return u_email;
    }

    public void setU_email(String u_email) {
        this.u_email = u_email;
    }

    public String getU_password() {
        return u_password;
    }

    public void setU_password(String u_password) {
        this.u_password = u_password;
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserTransRepositiory extends JpaRepository<UserTransfer, String>  {

    @Query(value ="SELECT " + "new paddelec.backend.model.UserTransfer(u.u_email,u.u_password)"
            +" FROM tokens t JOIN users u ON t.u_email=u.u_email WHERE t.token= ?1")
    UserTransfer findByToken(String Token);
}
```

This is my Code I try to generate a UserTranfer Object. The regular TokenTransfer and User Repository works just fine. But here I am getting the "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: *.UserTransfer" Exception.

Comment: It wont, need entity class. UserTransfer should be entity class.

Comment: I highly recommend you to getting started with the basics of JPA in Spring. [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) you can find an example of how an entity class should look like. Please show a little bit more initiative and research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserTransfer` must be a JPA entity -> annotate the class with  `@Entity`

->

```
@Entity
public class UserTransfer{
    private String u_email;
    private String u_password;
```

Moreover don't forget that each entity must have an `@Id` . Example : if the u_email is the primary key , annotate it with `@Id`